# How to: Retrieve an attachment image from post and output it

Tags: attachments, author, forms

If anyone can help me I would be gratefull!

---

I got a *gravity form* with the post_type fields including the submit image when submited it displays the:

- title
- content
- image
- tags

**So my question is:**

When I go to single.php I posted a code:  `get_related_author_posts();`  which calls the authors last two posts in function.php.

*Please take a look at the code, that contains/illustrates the problem: http://pastie.org/1926079*

---

I need a little help from my friends the wordpress gurus :)

Thank You all in advance. I'm still learning the more advanced functions but this is where I'm stuck:)

Comment: I edited your Q for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `wp_get_attachment_image()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)), which returns a fully-formed HTML IMG tag:

```
<?php 
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon ); 
?>
```

I assume you already know how to get the attachment image ID?

The default image size is `thumbnail`, but you can pass any standard image size (e.g. `full`, `large`, `medium`), or any custom image size added via `add_image_size()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the functions you need [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) (see "Related" at the bottom).

Comment: I'm lost, still can't get the image to be previews. I'll try harder :D